# Alamofire Nested Requests

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I need to make three different requests to the same API. None of these calls are dependent on the other. I currently have my requests nested like so:

```
API.getPopularMovies() { responseObject, error in
        if let results = responseObject {
            self.popularMovies = results

            self.API.getNowPlayingMovies() { responseObject, error in
                if let results = responseObject {
                    self.nowPlayingMovies = results

                    self.API.getUpcomingMovies() { responseObject, error in
                        if let results = responseObject {
                            self.upcomingMovies = results

                            self.movies = [self.popularMovies, self.nowPlayingMovies, self.upcomingMovies]
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like this may not be a good approach, and am looking for some guidance towards a better way of going about this. Currently, the resulting arrays seem to properly populate my table view, but I can't help but feel like this nested approach is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If none of your operations are dependent, then why do you nest them? I see that you don't reload your UITableView until the third one completes - if that's a hard requirement, then they *are* dependent.

When they are dependent, this kind of nesting is sometimes called a 'Pyramid of Doom'. A great way to clean it up is to wrap the nested code as a monad, which would allow the following:

- Code can be chained neatly, rather than nested, improving readability.
- You can use single rather than repeated error handling
- Any final/always tasks can be expressed neatly.

This is called a Promise. Here's an excellent [tutorial on how they work.](http://khanlou.com/2016/08/promises-in-swift/)

And there's some great libraries. [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) is a popular one.

Comment: You're right - they're definitely dependent. I looked into your provided links, and I think they're more than enough to get me on the right path. Thanks Jasper!

Comment: You're welcome friend. I used the tutorial from Ray Wenderlich to get started too. It came with a concrete sample app, though you have to sign up for a Flickr API key to try it.  https://www.raywenderlich.com/145683/getting-started-promises-promisekit